# C++ DLL not loading because of a reference to a non-existent function that is not called

Tags: c++, dll

In a DLL I have the following code that conditionally calls the Windows 8 function IsImmersiveProcess(). The DLL does not load on Windows 7 since this function is not present. Because this function is not actually called, what can I do to force the DLL to load into memory ?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <VersionHelpers.h>

...

if ( IsWindows8OrGreater() ) 
  IsImmersive = IsImmersiveProcess ( GetCurrentProcess() );
```

The error I get from C# when loading this DLL is:

```
Unable to load DLL 'd.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
```

### -

-

Thanks all. My final code based on the answers is as follows:

```
BOOL (WINAPI *pIsImmersiveProcess) ( HANDLE hProcess );
byte IsImmersive = 0;

pIsImmersiveProcess = (BOOL (WINAPI *) ( HANDLE hProcess ))
  GetProcAddress ( GetModuleHandle ( L"User32.dll" ), "IsImmersiveProcess" );

if ( pIsImmersiveProcess ) 
  IsImmersive = pIsImmersiveProcess ( GetCurrentProcess() );
```

Comment: You could load the library that contains the function (using `LoadLibrary`) and get the function's pointer using `GetProcAddress` and check if the pointer is NULL or not.  If it isn't NULL, then make the call via the pointer.  You won't even need the check for `IsWindows80OrGreater()` if you used that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the compiler and linker is concerned the function is called.

There are two ways to avoid that:

- Exclude the call at compile time so that the compiler knows it isn't called.
- Avoid a compile time reference to the function and obtain its address at runtime.

For the first approach, you can specialize a template based on the compile time known Windows version.

But if you want a single DLL for all supported Windows versions, then you need to go with the second approach, essentially using `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: The latter option is better handled using your linker's Delay Load feature, if it has one (for example, in Visual Studio, see [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx)). That allows code to static-link to DLL functions normally, but allows the linker to point the references to special stub code that load the DLL functions dynamically at runtime the first time they are called. Best of both worlds.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: But doesn't it resolve all the imported functions from a DLL when one of them is called for the first time? If so then that would (or could) fail?